# laravel | add to wishes without login

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make when non auth user click to link "Add To wishes" these link going to addtowishes method and send parameter id.
After, first I check does cookie 'wishes' exist if not, I make empty array and in that array I add 'id' after I push this array in cookie.
in else case I get cookie 'wishes' and in that array I push id.But every time when i start method, cookie::get('wishes') is null.

```
public function addtowishes($id)
    {
        if(emptyArray(Cookie::get('wishes'))) {
            $wishes=Array();
            array_push($wishes,$id);
            $cookie = cookie('wishes', $wishes, 500);

        }else {
              $cookie=Cookie::get('wishes');
            array_push($cookie->getValue(), $id);
            $cookie = cookie('wishes', $cookie->getValue(), 500);
            dd($cookie);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set with the function [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php)

also note that the expire parameter is a unix timestamp. therefore 500 will always be expired. Use `time()+60*60*24*30` for 30 days for example